# Can a married couple file for Express Entry if one of us is temporarily not in Canada?

Tags: canada, resident-permit, express-entry

My husband and I are in Canada where he is on a work visa. I have joined him as a dependant. We are planning to file permanent residency by the end of December; my husband will be the primary applicant. However, I might have to travel back to my home country in the next 3 months. Is it possible to file the PR application if my husband and I are in different locations/countries.

Comment: Are you both in Canada? Or is one of you in Canada and the other in a foreign country?

Comment: Currently we both are in canda. But I will have to travel back in 3 months.

Comment: Yes its possible. Need more details though.